# Solve $y' = \cos^2(y)-1$ with $y(\pi)=2\pi$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The exercise is to solve the initial value problem:

> $y' = \cos^2(y)-1 =: f(y)$ with $y(\pi)=2\pi$

In the lectures we proved a theorem, that tells us something like:

> Let $(y_-,y_+)$ be the largest interval around $y_0:=2\pi$, s.t. $f(y)\neq 0$ for $y\in (y_-,y_+)$. Then there is a solution $\varphi : ... \rightarrow (y_-,y_+) , x\mapsto F^{-1}(x-x_0)$ (where $x_0 := \pi$), where $F : (y_-,y_+) \rightarrow ..., y\mapsto \int_{y_0}^y \frac{1}{s}ds$.

However, this doesn't seem really helpful, since $f(y_0) = f(2\pi) = 0$, so $(y_-,y_+) = \emptyset$
.

So, is there a solution? If there is, how can I find it? If there isn't, how can I prove that? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the constant function $y(x)=2\pi$ that is definitely a solution. Check the unicity assumptions

Comment: Ahh, yes; of course! Sadly, I don't know, how to prove uniqueness, the theorem doesn't say anything about this in this case.